# New Relic: Obtain EC2 memory statistics via AMI appliance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've integrated our AWS EC2 environment with New Relic via the New Relic AMI appliance. I'm trying to avoid installing the client-side agent on the each of the EC2 instances.

I have enabled the following agents on the AMI appliance:

```
ec2
ebs
elb
rds 
sqs
sns
ec
ecr
```

I am able to view statistics on the CPU utilization, Disk I/O and Network I/O which is really great. However, I am not able to obtain the EC2 instances memory statistics.

What do I need to do to gather memory statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage isn't visible to the hypervisor so you need to install a script that sends the information to CloudWatch. Amazon document exactly how to do that on [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/mon-scripts.html).

Basically, a script is run by cron that sends a custom metric to CloudWatch. You should use an IAM role to allow the instance to talk to CloudWatch as best practice, but you can't change the IAM Role of a running instance, as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), you'd need to launch a new instance, even from a snapshot is fine. You can store your credentials on the EC2 instance, it's not a great idea but it is practical and may be necessary.

**Update**
Background information: CPU utilisation, network I/O, and EBS I/O is externally visible to the hypervisor and easily measured, so it's easy to put into CloudWatch. Memory use is different. The operating system is allocated a chunk of RAM and it's 100% dedicated to that instance, but the hypervisor doesn't know what the operating system is doing with the RAM. While the OS may tell you it's only using 25% of the memory it may be using 50% as file cache and only have 25% free. Also, even if the memory really isn't being used it's still allocated to that instance/OS. Basically there's no way for the hypervisor to know how much RAM is actually in use, and it's dedicated to the instance anyway. This is why if you want to know actual RAM usage something has to run within the guest operating system.

Comment: I have setup the script that reports to CloudWatch however the memory usage statistics are not been displayed in New Relic. As I mentioned, I can view details about the CPU utilisation, network I/O and disk I/O but nothing regarding the memory. I don't feel that it will be a good solution to use New Relic to monitor the CPU, disk etc and CloudWatch for the memory. Surely there is a way to get memory monitoring in New Relic?

Comment: I don't know anything about New Relic, just CloudWatch. You will have to have some kind of agent running in the OS to get information about memory, it's not visible to the hypervisor, and even if it was you couldn't access it. So you install the Amazon scripts and pull it from CloudWatch, or you install some kind of New Relic specific agent that does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. Do you know the technical reason why this script needs to be installed to obtain memory stats but the information regarding the CPU, disk and network does not require a push from the script?

Comment: I've updated my answer